# How to establish VNC connection to LightDM?

Tags: networking, lightdm, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm looking to do a remote connection to a **Ubuntu 16.04** machine through **VNC**. I'm using **Remmina** on client-side and I'm able to connect easily after the **LightDM** login, but I'm unable to perform the login on server-side remotely from the client.

I tried following different guides, but I ever get something like: *'unable to connect'*. I need to leave the **Ubuntu 16.04** machine headless, so turn it on and perform the login remotely from another machine. How could I do that?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: VNC by default will 'echo'  what is on the screen. This may not be what you want with a headless system. If must be VNC and no monitor attached you may be required to set up a display  before vncserver starts.

Comment: You have the tag 'remote-desktop' on your question. Checkout this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391164/setting-up-cross-platform-vnc-system/391199#391199) to use RDP or "Remote Desktop Protocol"  on a headless system.